# How to call asp.net web API with Following object As Parameter

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api

Not able to hit the API Method with object Containing

`#<Hashie::Mash tag`

I have tried the json object which is working fine , but now Client says Input Will be from AWS API which is

`#<Hashie::Mash bounce=#<Hashie::Mash bounceSubType="General"` `bounceType="Permanent" bouncedRecipients=[] >`

in above case how Can i Implement this.

Can Any one tell me how to Achieve the same.

Comment: you have some code or trying just like this  ?

Comment: yes, i have asp.net web api method and which is working for the Json

Comment: facing issue with the following parameter 

#<Hashie::Mash bounce=#<Hashie::Mash bounceSubType="General" bounceType="Permanent" bouncedRecipients=[#<Hashie::Mash action="failed" diagnosticCode="smtp; 550 5.

Comment: Please Help me... Thank you